# Recyclerview with Corner radius background

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, background, rounded-corners

I am using a recyclerview with rounded  corners ( using a drawable with a corner radius for the background) here's my code :

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:clipChildren="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_background"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_16dp"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:reverseLayout="true"
    app:stackFromEnd="false" />
```

now I was expecting the items of the recyclerview to scroll below the corners but the result was like this  :

[image]

I am looking to find a way to make items scroll below the corner radius as they fade, any hints and suggestions?

Comment: try to add the background in your adapter instead of adding like this

Comment: How to do that ? any more details ?

Comment: You can try to add white background and this purple gradient foreground, thus viewholders will be hidden by foreground

Comment: I assume the gradient background is the background to the ViewGroup_ for the _RecyclerView_. If so, it will always be behind all of the _ViewGroup's_ children. You will have to replicate the background as a new view and overlay it on top of the _RecyclerView_ to get the effect you want. What is the background? Is it an XML drawable? Can you post it?

Answer (score 2):

`android:clipToOutline="true"` should work for this case. This required API-31 . So u can move that layout to layout-v31 . to make it work below 31 We can wrap `RecyclerView` inside and `CardView` with wrap height . below is an example which worked for me .

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:foreground="@drawable/bg_rounded_black_outline"
                    app:cardElevation="0dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this property:

```
android:clipToOutline="true"
```